# How to get whole array from service Angular?

Tags: angular

There is a typical service Angular:

```
class Service {
    private a: number[] = [];

    constructor() {

        this.a.push(1);

        setTimeout(() => this.a.push(4), 5000);

    }

    getArray() {
        return this.a;
    }
}
```

Component:

```
constructor(private service: Service) {
      // How to get whole array from service here and render?
}
```

How to get whole array from service and render?

Comment: Where `setTimeout(() => this.a.push(4), 5000);` is async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// export this class 
export class Service {

// make this public so that it can be accessed in other files after importing this class
   public a: number[] = [];

   constructor() {

    this.a.push(1);

    setTimeout(() => this.a.push(4), 5000);

   }

   getArray() {
    return this.a;
  }
}
```

Component:

```
import {Service} from './path_to_service_file';

constructor(private service: Service) {
      // How to get whole array from service here and render?
   console.log(this.service.a) // <- this is your array

}
```

Comment: This `console.log(this.service.a)` returns me only `[1]` because `push(4)` works async

Comment: use observable instead

Comment: There is not a traditional way to solve this in JS?

Comment: you can use promise if you want

Comment: How? Wrap all in another promise? How to make this properly?